# Bootstrap Scroll Spy highlights wrong id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need help with my bootstrap scrollspy setting. It is highlighting the wrong div id (always the last one). Anyone can help me, please?

Code:

content:

```
<body style="heigt: 100%" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#side-menu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav id="side-menu" class="col-xs-3 bs-docs-sidebar" data-gumshoe-header>
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked fixed" data-gumshoe>
                <li>
                    <a href="#GroupA">Group A</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#GroupB">Group B</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#GroupC">Group C</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div id="GroupA">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="GroupB">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="GroupC">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**// Edit:** Picture of page [image: Wrong thing]

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and JQuery 2.2.4.

Regards

Comment: Look at my edited answer. The problem is not enough space for scrolling vertically. With more content in your divs, the code works properly.
Also consider using CSS `margin` on your divs rather than using millions of `br` :)

Comment: I noticed you have `style="heigt: 100%"` instead of `style="height: 100%"` in your `body` element.

Comment: @BartoszT add your last comment in your answer and i will accept your answer. That was it! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you're welcome :) One small letter and an hour of discussion :D Good luck and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolled element should be `position: relative` style.

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#requires-relative-positioning

**Edit**

Your divs height are too small. Scroll area is to short for scroll-spy.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o93q4maf/

**Edit2**

As [@Lars mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899153/bootstrap-scroll-spy-highlights-wrong-id/44899238#comment76778127_44899153) the problem was a typo: `style="heigt: 100%"` instead of `style="height: 100%"` in body element.

Comment: I replaced `style="height: 100%` with `style="position: relative;"` at `body` but it doenst work

Comment: Are you sure you have included scrollspy.js plugin? I have no idea. Your markup seems to be ok.

Comment: Yeah the scrollspy.js is included in the bootstrap.min.js file, or not?

Comment: Yes, it is by default. What about `data-offset`? By default its value is `10` but try to experiment. I think your divs are not high enough to be spied properly.

Comment: I will try that but at JSFiddle my Site is functionaly O.o https://jsfiddle.net/75qL7ggt/ Don't know why

Comment: Fiddle is not working to me. Its behaviour is as you described in question - scrolls to last div. I think the problem is divs' height.

Comment: I Tried to Experiment with the Data-offset Attribute but there is No change. Tried following values: 20, 40, 50, 60.